# Find the MLE density function of uniform [-\theta,\theta]

Tags: maximum-likelihood, density-function, uniform-distribution

For $X_1,\dots,X_n$, i.i.d $X_n \sim \mathrm{unif}[-\theta,\theta]$, the ML: $\hat\theta_{MLE}=\mathrm{max}\{-X_{(1)},X_{(n)}\}$. Find the density function. Hint: For $x_1,\dots,x_n$ : $\textrm{max}\{-x_{(1)},x_{(n)}\}=max\{|x_1|,\dots,|x_n|\}$.

Here is my work:

First i find the CDF  for $\hat\theta_{MLE}$ and then differentiate with respect to $x$:

\begin{align}
F_{\hat\theta_{MLE}}(x) &=
 P(\text{max}\{-X_{(1)},X_{(n)}\}\leq x) \\
&= P(\text{max}\{|X_{(1)}|, \dots ,|X_{(n)}|\}\leq x) \\
&= P(\text{max}\{|X_{(1)}|\}, \dots , \text{max}\{|X_{(n)}|\}\leq x) \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(|X_i|\leq x) \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(-x\leq X_i \leq x)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n} F_X(x)-F_X(-x)\\
&= \left(F_X(x)-F_X(x)\right)^{n}\\
&= \left(\frac{x}{\theta}\right)^{n}
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
 \frac{d}{dx}\left[\left(\frac{x}{\theta}\right)^{n}\right] &= n\frac{x^{n-1}}{\theta^n}\\
 &= f_{\hat\theta_{MLE}}(\hat\theta) \ \text{,}\  0\leq x \leq \theta
\end{align*}

Is this correct?

Comment: Think of typos in what you have written.

Comment: This is a FAQ: See [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=uniform+mle+theta+is%3Aquestion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few extra (and less) steps:
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
F_{\hat\theta_{MLE}}(x) &=
 \mathbb P_\theta(\text{max}\{-X_{(1)},X_{(n)}\}\leq x)\\
&= \mathbb P_\theta(-X_{(1)}\le x,X_{(n)}\leq x)  \tag{definition}\\
&= \mathbb P_\theta(X_{(1)}\ge -x,X_{(n)}\leq x)  \tag{inversion}\\
&= \mathbb P_\theta(X_1\ge -x,\ldots,X_n\ge -x,\\
&\qquad \qquad X_1\leq x,\ldots,X_n\le x) \\
&= \mathbb P_\theta(|X_1|\le x,\ldots,|X_n|\le x)\\
&=  \cancel{\mathbb P_\theta(\text{max}\{|X_{(1)}|, \dots ,|X_{(n)}|\}\leq x)}\tag{useless} \\
&=  \cancel{  \mathbb P_\theta(\text{max}\{|X_{(1)}|\}, \dots , \text{max}\{|X_{(n)}|\}\leq x)}\tag{incorrect}\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n}  \mathbb P_\theta(|X_i|\leq x) \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n}  \mathbb P_\theta(-x\leq X_i \leq x)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n} \{F_X(x)-F_X(-x)\}\\
&= \{F_X(x)-F_X(-x)\}^{n}\tag{typo}\\
&= \left(\frac{\min\{\theta,x\}}{\theta}\right)^{n}\tag{correction}
\end{align}